# Selenium, clicking a button using the outer HTML as xpaths dont increment

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I am scraping from a table using selenium as it is js table

The table has 25 entries on each page I wish to click to the next page scrape the table. and repeat.

The code I could usually use for button clicks is below. In this web page the xpath does not increment equally

```
button_next = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/nav[1]/ul/li[9]/a')
```

however, the outer html tag  does increment in such a way. **Is there a way to use the find element method with the outer html text?**

outer html text looks like this.

```
<a class="page-link" data-page="2" tabindex="-1">Next</a>
```

the page index incrementes each time so could be used if I can select a button with it?

further info on how the pages are coded xpath/outer html.

```
#page no

#1  /html/body/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/nav[1]/ul/li[9]/a
# <a class="page-link" data-page="2" tabindex="-1">Next</a>

#2 /html/body/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/nav[1]/ul/li[9]/a
# <a class="page-link" data-page="3" tabindex="-1">Next</a>

#3 /html/body/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/nav[1]/ul/li[10]/a
# <a class="page-link" data-page="4" tabindex="-1">Next</a>

#4 /html/body/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/nav[1]/ul/li[10]/a
#  <a class="page-link" data-page="5" tabindex="-1">Next</a>

#5 /html/body/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/nav[1]/ul/li[10]/a
# <a class="page-link" data-page="6" tabindex="-1">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking of a way to find the "Next" button you just need:

```
button_next = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[text()="Next"]')
```

Comment: Yes that works well, I need more revision but you helped me reach a deadline today. Thank-you